# Is there a word that means near-daily?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, time

I am trying to write a document that describes the frequency with which we perform a task.  It is usually done daily, however I don't want to be tied to having to do it daily.  Is there a more professional word I can use to mean *near-daily*?

Comment: What is wrong with *near-daily* itself?  I don't think you would be misunderstood.

Comment: I doubt this word exist, but I think that you could use hours as time unit. Hours seem more professional than daily (e.g. "36/48 hours"~"near-daily")

Comment: You might just say, "This task is typically performed daily."

Comment: @cornbread ninja: It is not matter of misunderstanding, Danielle is searching for more professional word.

Comment: You could spell out, or provide an example of, what might stop it being done: "The task is performed daily unless [something prevents it]"

Answer (score 6):

The phrase ***most days*** is widely used: "*Most days* we have a staff meeting."

Comment: For any other context, I'd agree. But OP specifically asked for a ***more professional*** word/expression. I think "most days" has a very casual/informal ring to it. He in fact would probably be forced into some more convoluted but vague phrasing, such as *"at least 3-4 times per week"* (5-6 if it's a 7-day week context).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a word that means "near-daily" or "most days".   Besides those terms, consider "almost-daily", "at most daily", and "daily (as needed)".  If the task is always performed at the same time of day, you might refer to "the *X* task (as needed)" where *X* is, for example, dawn, morning, noon, afternoon, evening, or a specific time.

*[Usually](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usually)* and related words lead to phrasings such as  *[nominally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nominally) daily*, *[normally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normally) daily*, *[notionally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notionally) daily*, *[ordinarily](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordinarily) daily*, and *usually daily*.

Comment: I'd have to recommend against "notionally daily" ~ but I'm still glad jwpat included it in the list.